# Python Reading a Pastebin Raw

Tags: python

```
Start = 5 #Starts Reading at line 5
End = 10 #Stops Reading at line 10



URL = "https://pastebin.com/raw/"
contents = requests.get(URL).text.split('\n')
```

this is my current code to reading a pastebin, I was wondering if there was a way where i could start reading at a specific line and stop reading at the second specific line.

My pastebin looks something this

[image]

Comment: `splitlines` (or `split('\n')`) gives you a list. How would you slice a list to give the lines you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`split` gives you a list so just slice the list from start to end.

```
URL = "https://pastebin.com/raw/"
contents = requests.get(URL).text.split('\n')[start:end]
```

Comment: Thanks I completely forgot about split :) this is my code now 


```def Run(min,max,i,w): 
    for x in contents[min-1:max]:
        print(x)
```